# Solving haar wavelet transform

Tags: information-retrieval, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I am trying to understand the haar wavelet transform. Could somebody confirm if my answer is correct or tell me what I am doing wrong. This is the problem I tried to solve:

[image]

If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Example

Answer (score 0):

If I compute the fast wavelet transform (FWT) of *r* using the Haar wavelet filters, I expect to get *r1*. So if that was the question, *r1* is the answer.

Comment: More precisely, the _r1_ is the first level, whereas the _r2_ is the second level of a multi-scale Haar transform.